# Django Crispy Form renders JSON as HTML

Tags: python, json, ajax, django, django-forms

When my crispy form is submitted for a second time, it displays JSON instead of redirecting to the success page or displaying errors. The first time works like a charm.

**Validator.js is not fired on the second submission**. As a result, Ajax does not handle the JSON, which is why it is displayed as HTML.

I have tried `event.preventDefault();`, removing `type="submit"` from the submit button, removing `action` and `method` from the form and grabbing it from a hidden input.

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/thomasmeagher/Wilbur)

**JSON rendered as HTML**

```
{"success": false, "form_html": "\n\n<form  class=\"form-crispy\" ... }
```

[image]

**HTML form**

```
<form  class="form-crispy" id="form-grab" next="/transactions/" action="/transactions/add/" method="post" >
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='AfUGrMclChV1ctI6F5iw93EYyKpuB5Oh' />
    FIELDS
    ....
    <button  type="submit" class="btn button-submit" id="form-submit">Submit</button>
    <a href="/transactions/" class="button-cancel" role="button">Cancel</a>
</form>

<script src="/static/budget/js/validator.js"></script>
```

**Validator.js**

```
$("#form-submit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Fired');

    var form = $('#form-grab');

    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (!(data['success'])) {
                form.replaceWith(data['form_html']);
            }
            else {
                var next = form.attr('next');
                window.location.replace(next);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            form.find('.error-message').show()
        }
    });
});
```

**Views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/', redirect_field_name='next')
@json_view
def add_transaction(request):
    user = get_user_in_session(request.session)
    data = {'user': user}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TransactionAddForm(request.POST, initial=data)
        if form.is_valid():
            budget = form.cleaned_data['budget']
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            amount = form.cleaned_data['amount']
            transaction_date = form.cleaned_data['transaction_date']
            creation_date = now().date()
            transaction = Transaction(
                    budget=budget,
                    description=description,
                    amount=amount,
                    transaction_date=transaction_date,
                    creation_date=creation_date
            )
            transaction.save()
            return {
                'success': True,
            }
        context = {}
        context.update(csrf(request))
        form_html = render_crispy_form(form, context=context)
        return {
            'success': False,
            'form_html': form_html,
        }
    else:
        form = TransactionAddForm(initial=data)
        return render(request, 'base_form.html', {
            'title': 'Add Transaction',
            'form': form,
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha,

I think the problem is in the `replaceWith` jquery method that removes not only the data but also the event handlers linked to the removed nodes of the html.

The possible solution is to reattach the event afterward the `replaceWith`. In your code above:

```
...
form.replaceWith(data['form_html']);
# reattach
$("#form-submit").on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  # continue with invoking ajax post function
});
```